# Import "airflow.operators.bash_operator" could not be resolved

Tags: python, airflow, ubuntu-22.04

[Please find attached error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5uDp.jpg)

1. At first all 3 airflow imports are errors it said "could not be resolved" so I use this code

```
pip install "apache-airflow[celery]==2.6.2" --constraint  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.2/constraints-3.11.txt"
```

2. then both below is OK now but only airflow.operators.bash_operator still error

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
```

i use python 3.11.0  apache_airflow 2.6.2  on ubuntu 22.04 vscode

i am so new to airflow pls help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Airflow 2.6.2 your import for bash operator should be

```
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
```

Please check example here
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.2/_modules/airflow/example_dags/example_bash_operator.html

source code here
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.6.2/airflow/operators/bash.py